# Error when checking target: expected classifier to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras

I'm triyinto to fit a vgg_face detector of the following way:

```
nb_class = len(y) //11

vgg_model = VGGFace(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), model='resnet50')
last_layer = vgg_model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
out = Dense(nb_class, activation='softmax', name='classifier')(x)
vgg_model = Model(vgg_model.input, out)
vgg_model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

vgg_model.fit(X, y)
```

In order to do this, I have the X with the following shape (11, 224, 224, 3,) and y with the following shape (11,).

When I call to fit function I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected classifier to have
>   shape (11,) but got array with shape (1,)

Where is the error if in the X and y there is 11 items in order to fit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your target shape...

if you have 1D integer encoded target you can use sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss function

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,100))
y = np.random.randint(0,3, 1000)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim = 100),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Otherwise, if you have one-hot encoded your target in order to have 2D shape (n_samples, n_class) you can use categorical_crossentropy

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,100))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,3, 1000)).values

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim = 100),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your target is not one-hot encoded, which `categorical_crossentropy` expects. You can one-hot encode your target like this:

```
from tensorflow import keras 

y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, nb_class)
```

Assuming that I correctly understood that you had `nb_class` different categories (otherwise just remove `nb_class`). Here is the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#to_categorical-function).

```
keras.utils.to_categorical([1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1])
```

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```